# Cannot resubmit job to ml-engine because "A job with this id already exists"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to submit a job to gcloud ml-engine. For reference the job is using [this sample provided by Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census)

It went through the first time, but with errors unrelated to this question, and now I am trying reissue the command after having corrected my errors:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
                                    --stream-logs \
                                    --runtime-version 1.0 \
                                    --job-dir $GCS_JOB_DIR \
                                    --module-name trainer.task \
                                    --package-path trainer/ \
                                    --region us-east1 \
                                    -- \
                                    --train-files $TRAIN_GCS_FILE \
                                    --eval-files $EVAL_GCS_FILE \
                                    --train-steps $TRAIN_STEPS
```

, where `$JOB_NAME` = `census`. Unfortunately, it seems that I cannot proceed with resubmitting the job unless I change `$JOB_NAME` to be something like `census2`, then `census3`, etc. for every new job.

The following is the error I receive:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) Project [my-project-name]
is the subject of a conflict: Field: job.job_id Error: A job with this
id already exists.
```

Is this part of the design to not be able to resubmit using the same job name or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but in [Google's sample code for flowers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/sample.sh), the error is avoided by appending the date and time to the job id as shown on line 22, e.g.,

```
declare -r JOB_ID="flowers_${USER}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
```

Comment: To all pedants: don't try ISO format.
`job_id Error: A name should start with a letter and contain only letters, numbers and underscores.`

Answer (score 3):

Like Chunck just said, simply try setting `JOB_NAME` as:

`JOB_NAME="census_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"`